# Is there something like easy ubuntu for Fedora 18 (to install common non-free software)

Tags: fedora

I have just installed fedora 18 on my laptop. It is my home machine, so I will be using it for multimedia and similar things.

Having come from Linux Mint, I realize thee is a lot of non-free stuff missing. Drivers for ATI graphics, Skype, and such like.

I remember in the early days of Ubuntu there was a package easyubuntu which downloaded and installed a number of useful but non-free packages and drivers. Looking about I see Fedora had fedora-frog. I tried this but it says it is only for fedora 10 and 11.

Is there any modern equivalent of this for Fedora 18?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There have been many of these over the years. The latest attempt is called EasyLife. Here's a link to the project along with some other projects attempting to do the same:

- [EasyLife](http://easylifeproject.org/)
- [Autoplus](http://www.dnmouse.org/autoten/)
- [Fedora Utils](http://fedorautils.sourceforge.net/)

#### screenshots

**EasyLife**

[image: ss of easylife]

**AutoPlus**

[image: ss of autoplus]

**Fedora Utils**

[image: ss of fedora utils]

Answer (score 0):

Also exist PostInstallerF. [PostInstallerF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/postinstaller/) will install all necessary, after to run first time Fedora. Its easy for new user. PostInstallerF contains everything you need.